# Checking FLS in apex code for another user

Tags: apex, permissions, field-level-security

So basically what I need is to check field-level security in apex class but for some specific user, i.e. not for my current user (bunch of schema describe would do the trick here).

So far I've ended up querying **FieldPermissions** object directly to figure this out. The problem is that this object doesn't have any info re field being createable. It only has **PermissionsRead** & **PermissionsEdit** field. Is it possible somehow to figure out if field is createable for specific user?

In short, what I need is kinda **DescribeFieldResult.isCreateable(userId)**

Maybe there is a better way to do this, some already implemented libraries/packages for this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Below is the snippet of code with FieldPermissions query in action:

```
        [
            SELECT
                Id,
                ParentId,
                SObjectType,
                Field,
                PermissionsEdit,
                PermissionsRead
            FROM
                FieldPermissions
            WHERE
                ParentId IN (
                    SELECT
                        PermissionSetId
                    FROM
                        PermissionSetAssignment
                    WHERE
                        AssigneeId = :userId    
                )
                AND
                SObjectType = :ObjectUtilities.toFullyQualifiedObjectName(objectName)
        ]
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve at a high level? If we know *why* you want this information, we might be able to pose a workaround.

Comment: Yep, sure. So we have some sort of requests (coming from mobile devices through Rest API) which represent actions taken by users when devices were offline. Request is like "create account", "update contact name" etc. We are putting all such requests in kinda queue (custom object). Then there is scheduled job to process all those requests. The job is scheduled by admin. When the processing happens we would like to enforce FLS of each specific user who sent that request (cause we have concerns about mobile requests being manipulated etc.). It seems really not safe for us just execute request.

Comment: @AdrianLarson added description of my use case in the comment above.